# returning null value when importing mat file in to c++ code

Tags: c++, matlab, mat, matlab-deployment

I am new to c++ and I am trying to import a mat file in to my c++ program There is a separate class to get all the properties of the matrix in the mat file. Following is my header file readmat.h

```
#ifndef READMAT_H
#define READMAT_H
#include "mat.h"
#include "matrix.h"
#include "mex.h"



class readmat
{
private:
const size_t *dimarray;
const char **dir;
MATFile *pmat;
int ndir;
mxArray *pa;
const char *file;
int minute;
int second;
const char *name;
double *pointer;
bool isdouble;
void getmxpointer();

public:

//with default value
readmat(const char *f);
//  get number of dimensions
int getnumbrofdimensions();
// get pointer to array
double* getarraypointer();
// get pointer to each dimension size
const size_t* dimensionpointer();
//number of elements
int numberofelements();


};

#endif
```

This is my readmat.cpp.

```
#include "readmat.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "mat.h"
#include "matrix.h"
#include "mex.h"
using namespace std;

// set the file name
readmat::readmat(const char *f)
{
    file = f;
}

void readmat::getmxpointer()
{
    pmat = matOpen(file, "r");
    if (pmat == NULL) {
        cout << "Error opening file" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        dir = (const char **)matGetDir(pmat, &ndir);
        if (dir == NULL) {
            printf("Error reading directory of file %s\n", file);

        }
        else if (ndir>1)
       {
           cout << "The number of variables are larger than 1" << endl;
       }
        else
        {
            mxFree(dir);
            matClose(pmat);
            pmat = matOpen(file, "r");
            for (int q = 0; q < 1; q++)
           {
                pa = matGetNextVariableInfo(pmat, &name);

            }
            matClose(pmat);
        }

    }


}

int readmat::getnumbrofdimensions()
{
    getmxpointer();
    return mxGetNumberOfDimensions(pa);
}

double * readmat::getarraypointer()
{
    getmxpointer();
    pointer = mxGetPr(pa);
    return pointer;

}

 const size_t*  readmat::dimensionpointer()
{
    getmxpointer();
    dimarray =  mxGetDimensions(pa);
    return dimarray;
}

 int readmat::numberofelements()
 {
     getmxpointer();
     return mxGetNumberOfElements(pa);
 }
```

Following is my main.cpp

```
#include "mat.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> /* For strcmp() */
#include <stdlib.h> /* For EXIT_FAILURE, EXIT_SUCCESS */
#include <vector> /* For STL */
#include "readmat.h"


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i;
    int m;
    int elements;
    int numberofdimension;
    double *datapoint;
    const char *file = "pqfile.mat";
    const size_t* dimepointer;

    readmat thismat(file);
    numberofdimension = thismat.getnumbrofdimensions();
    dimepointer = thismat.dimensionpointer();
    cout << "The dimensions are  ";
    for (m = 0; m < numberofdimension; m++)
    {
        cout << *(dimepointer + m);
        cout << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "This is the number of dimensions  ";
    cout << numberofdimension << endl;
    datapoint = thismat.getarraypointer();
    elements = thismat.numberofelements();
    cout << "The array elements ";
    cout << elements;
    cout << endl;
    cout << thismat.pointer;
   /*for (n = 0; n < elements; n++)
    {
   cout << *(arraypint + m);
   cout << " ";
    }*/

    cin >> i;
    return 0;

}
```

But here except for the **getarraypointer()** function others working fine. getarraypointer() returns null value and in the watch window for the pointer datapoint which the return from getarraypointer() is assigned unable to read memory message is there. When I run the same code segment in main it runs without a problem. Here it's this code.

```
MATFile *pmat;
int i;
int   ndir;
const char **dir;
const char *file = "pqfile.mat";
mxArray *pa;
const char *name;
double *in1pr;



pmat = matOpen(file, "r");
if (pmat == NULL) {
    printf("Error reopening file %s\n", file);
    return(1);
}

//dir = (const char **)matGetDir(pmat, &ndir);
for (i = 0; i<1; i++) {
    pa = matGetNextVariable(pmat, &name);
    }
matClose(pmat);
in1pr = mxGetPr(pa);
cout << "Value of variable: ";
cout << *(in1pr + 5) << endl;
cin >> i;
return 0;
```

Comment: They're not equivalent codes. Ex: consider the lifetime of `pmat` in both scenarios. Honestly, this design needs attention, as you have multiple issues. You're leaking memory like a sieve leaks rainwater in multiple places. I'd advise a redesign with coding being the *last* thing done; not the first.

Comment: I don't think lifetime of pmat is the issue here. Because after matClose(pmat); it still works fine in Main function. Thank you for you advice. I am very new to c++ and coding. I hope to learn those with this project.